# Update a field from all documents in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am very new to Firebase and I am not sure how to update the same field in all documents in one collection.

```
  return db.collection('collection').get().then((snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

      doc.update({'field': 1});
      
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

I am running this code in a firebase function. There are no errors, but nothing is happening. I can't see anything in the documentation about this specific problem. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to return the result of all the `update()` calls to the caller, as otherwise it can't know when all asynchronous operations have completed:

```
  return db.collection('collection').get().then((snapshot) => {
    return Promise.all(snapshot.documents.map((doc) => {
      return doc.ref.update({'field': 1});
    }));
  });
```

The changes:

1. `return` the promise from `update()` so that it can be bubbled up to the Cloud Functions container.
2. Use `map` so that we get an array of promises.
3. Then use `Promise.all` so that we only complete (and thus terminate the Cloud Function) when all the updates have completed.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the quick help! I tried your changes, but the firebase-log says: "Error getting documents TypeError: snapshot.map is not a function". Do you know what went wrong ?

Comment: Oh right, that should be `snapshot.documents.map`. I fixed the code in my answer. I highly recommend keeping the reference docs handy while coding, as this type of mistake is easy to fix once you get used to reading those: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/QuerySnapshot#documents

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work...There are no errors, but nothing happens. I tried something different and this works for me. I am posting it as answer, if my approach is not good, please correct me, then other people know it is not the best way to do this. Thanks for your time Frank, I appreciate it.

Comment: There was another mistake in your code, as there's no `update` method on a `DocumentSnapshot`.  That should actually give a pretty explicit error message when invoked. I updated the code again for that mistake too. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#ref

Answer (score 0):

This approach did the thing for me... Don't know if this is a proper way (as said I am a beginner)

```
exports.scheduledFunction2 = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {

    return db.collection("collection")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        for(let i =0;i<querySnapshot.size;i++){

          var queryDocumentSnapshotTest = querySnapshot.docs[i];
          

          queryDocumentSnapshotTest.ref.update({'counter':1});

        }
        
  
        return null;
  
      } else {
       // do nothing
       console.log("No document corresponding to the query!");
        return null;
      }
    });
  
  
   
  });
```

Comment: This will **not** reliably work. The first `return null;` will run before the asynchronous `update` calls have completed, meaning that the Cloud Function may be aborted before the database updates have been committed.

Comment: Is there a quick solution for this...how can I wait before the return?

Comment: By using the code in my answer? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯